# call a method after webview success loaded an url in vue native

Tags: react-native, webview, vue-native

how can I call the `testing()` method after the  webview successfully loaded an url?

```
  <template>
        <web-view :source="{uri:'https://www.google.com'}" />
    </template>

    <script>
    import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";

    export default {
      name: "webview",
        components: {
        "web-view": WebView
      },
      methods:{
        testing(){
           console.log("something")
        }
      }
    };

    </script>
```